# How can I create javascript standalone executables, hosted by ChakraCore?

Tags: javascript, chakracore

I already know about [jsc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6(v=vs.100).aspx) (part of .NET SDK), that generates executables hosted by Windows Script Host.

Also I noticed that the latest Typescript versions, the tsc.exe (compiled javascript) is using ChakraCore.dll

So, what tool can I use to generate standalone executables, hosted by ChakraCore?
How the Typescript team creates the tsc.exe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the TypeScript team.

`tsc.exe` is a very basic C++ console app, which basically follows the steps described in the [Embedding ChakraCore page](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/wiki/Embedding-ChakraCore) on their Wiki for loading and running `tsc.js`.

Comment: What if I want to use Chakracore in my browser to run the NodeJs Scripts? I have my browser ready in C++ with basic functionalities, built chakracore using MSVS2017 , how do I integrate it to run along with my browser?

Comment: I don't see how that would be much different. Instead of the main function in the sample on the Wiki invoke the JavaScript engine from the browser with the referenced js files.